# Does universal regression exist?

Tags: regression

Unlike linear regression that only fit if the dataset vizualisation looks like linear line.

So what I mean with universal regression is regardless dataset visualization will be linear, polynomial, or exponential, the universal regression will auto detect it.

For example, if the dataset vizualisation looks like quadratic data by our eyes (talking subjectively), then the equation will draw paraboloic line $y=a(x+b)^{d}+c$ where universal regression will return $a=5,b=3,c=4,d=2$.

So is there a universal regression?

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no such regression.

Comment: If you mean "Is there a regression that will exactly recover the parameters of any possible expression?" then the answer is "No." If you mean "Is it possible to achieve a good fit to arbitrary training data?" then the answer is "Yes, use a basis that is larger than your training data. Using a high-degree polynomial or splines are two examples."

Comment: You probably want to learn about [nonparametric regression](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2241560), and [non-linear least squares regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cybenko universal approximation theorem for neural networks and Stone-Weierstrass theorem for polynomials both state that, under what should typically be reasonable conditions for a regression, functions can be approximated as well as is demanded.

In that sense, theorems like these can be seen as giving “universal” equations that will but able to fit decent regression models like linear, polynomial, or exponential, as long as you give enough flexibility (so don’t try to approximate a quadratic function with a linear polynomial).

The trouble is that these do not address how to estimate those equations in the presence of noise. For instance, if you throw a gigantic polynomial regression at a set of data, assuming that Stone-Weierstrass makes it likely to pick up on even complicated trends, you can pick up on coincidences in the data, rather than the true underlying pattern that you aim to model (and what Cybenko and Stone-Weierstrass mean can be approximated). Fighting this overfitting is where a lot of the magic of machine learning and predictive modeling happens (e.g., regularization).

If you want to allow for flexibly modeling nonlinear functions, a popular approach to a linear model (remember, it’s about linearity in the parameters) would be to use splines, rather than polynomials.

Comment: +1 There is another approximation theorem for Fourier series, although the name escapes me at the moment.

Comment: @Galen You probably mean Carleson’s theorem. The same gist applies: we can get as close as is demanded when we know the function to approximate, but the situation is muddied once the statisticians introduce an error term, since we have to guess the function by inferring it from both signal and noise.

Answer (score -1):

You need to restrict the kinds of equations you want your “universal regression” to find.

Suppose that you have 100 distinct values of $x$, and the value of $y$ for each of those $x$ values. Then there is always a polynomial which matches all those values exactly, **with zero error**.

It will in general be a 99th-degree polynomial.

I am sure that this is not what you want. But it is exactly what you asked for.

Accordingly the basic statement of what you mean by a “universal regression” has to be sharpened somehow.

Comment: So basically polynomial regression is universal regression

Comment: I would not consider that to be a universal regression, since it would (probably) be fitting the errors, not the conditional expected values. Consequently, there is no reason to expect such a regression to give performance that generalizes to new data; this method (probably) overfits. This is important, since the question is asking about how to have a regression general enough to figure out if the pattern is linear, quadratic, etc, while this approach does not do that. This approach would fit a complicated polynomial to data that fit a simple linear regression.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira Polynomial regression (either integer series, or fractional) doesn't work well for many functional relationships between DV and IV.